# PHP: Order a table by ascending order NOT database table/schema

Tags: php, html, foreach, echo

I am trying to order a table that has been written and created in HTML and PHP, for this I use a loop that gives me the information I need fed in from an XML document. 
For example what I could get from the XML is:

1. 2:10 Romford
2. 1:50 Crayford
3. 6:30 Keswick
4. 4:25 Richmond

These values all come from the same XML document and I cannot (due to request by client) store and pull the information back from a database schema. I am building the table as so:

```
<?php
$xml = simple_xml_load_file("xmlfeed");
$item = $xml->items;
?>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) { echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td></tr>"; }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I NEED to be able to have them in ascending order based on the time at the beginning, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: maybe `asort()` http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: That doesn't seem to help really...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. I guess your code might be different but it does what is needed...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=3&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N');
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)$xml), true); //convert to array
$list = [];
foreach ($array['response']['williamhill']['class']['type'] as $type => $typeData) {
    $typeId = $typeData['@attributes']['id'];
    $list[$typeId] = [
        'attributes' => $typeData['@attributes'],
        'market' => [],
    ];

    foreach ($typeData['market'] as $game) {
        $list[$typeId]['market'][] = $game;
    }

    usort($list[$typeId]['market'], function ($a, $b) {
        $aTime = strtotime($a['@attributes']['date'].' '. $a['@attributes']['time']);
        $bTime = strtotime($b['@attributes']['date'].' '. $b['@attributes']['time']);
        if ($aTime == $bTime) return 0;
        return ($aTime > $bTime) ? 1 : -1;
    });

}
```

Comment: This seemed to fail as the items may have more than one word in the name, meaning that it is impossible to have a generically sized array to print to the screen

Comment: Can you send over a small example of the xml you are getting? Especially xml that has the case you specified above.

Comment: It's an XML delivered by William Hill [here](http://cachepricefeeds.williamhill.com/openbet_cdn?action=template&template=getHierarchyByMarketType&classId=3&marketSort=--&filterBIR=N)